# How to apply conditional formatting rule to entire row with a regex

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, re2

I wanted to apply conditional formatting to any cell in column A with text `0.0` in it, so I made this custom formatting rule:

[image]

However I want the highlight to apply to entire row not just the cell, any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conditional formatting rules' formulae are applied like dragging a formula around  the range to be formatted, including the rules of absolute and relative reference.

You want to apply to `A2:Z` or whatever column comes last and the rule will be `=REGEXMATCH($A2, "0.0")`.

Note the `$` for the column, otherwise it will check B2 for column B.

Comment: ah right it's the apply to range part that i missed.. cool thanks!